# Using XLOOKUP in two different Sheets and having a variable array extent (VBA Coding)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, lookup, xlookup

Hello there I am very new to VBA coding and coding in general so I hope you can come up with a quick answer to my problem.

I am trying to get a XLookup-Formula into my vba-Code. The code is referencing to another Sheet ("Chart Plan" and is supposed to take the values in column "D" and "E" (starting from row 2) as fixed arrays down to the last row for the "Lookup array" and "return array". I want this to be variable as the "Chart Plan" is updated with different row numbers according to what I am working on. The formula then is supposed to return the values into the active worksheet (Column "J") and go through all the rows ("B" given as RC[-8] = Lookup value).
The problem, I guess, is that I don't really know how the syntax is for giving the arrays into the formula or is it something else entirly? Mixing between RC-Annotation and A1-Annotation maybe?

Thank you.

```
Dim aEndKP As Variant
Dim aStartKP As Variant
Dim aCN As Variant

Sub ChartPlanScript()

Dim row As Long
Dim last_row As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Array End KP

LReKP = Sheets("Chart Plan").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
aEndKP = Sheets("Chart Plan").Range("D2:D" & LReKP)

'Array Start KP

LRsKP = Sheets("Chart Plan").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row
aStartKP = Sheets("Chart Plan").Range("C2:C" & LRsKP)

'Array Chart Plan
 
LRCN = Sheets("Chart Plan").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row
aCN = Sheets("Chart Plan").Range("E2:E" & LRCN)
 
 
Set ws = Sheets(1)
ws.Activate

last_row = ws.Range("A5000").End(xlUp).row

For row = 2 To last_row
        If Range("A" & row).Value > 0 Then

         ws.Range("J" & row).Value = "=XLOOKUP(RC[-8],[aEndKP],[aCN],,1,1)"

        Else
       ws.Range("J" & row).Value = ""
    End If
Next row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have XLOOKUP on my version of Excel but this would be using VLOOKUP

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ChartPlanScript()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, last_row As Long
    Dim sCN As String

    'Chart Plan
    With Sheets("Chart Plan")
        last_row = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
        sCN = "'Chart Plan'!" & .Range("D2:E" & last_row).Address
    End With
     
    Set ws = Sheets(1)
    ws.Activate
    last_row = ws.Range("A5000").End(xlUp).row

    For i = 2 To last_row
        If ws.Cells(i, "A") > 0 Then
            ws.Range("J" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B" & i & "," & sCN & ",2,0)"
        Else
            ws.Cells(i, "J") = ""
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox i - 1 & " rows processed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted the syntax for the XLookup-Function and it worked like a charm! Thanks you :)